# How to get number of elements of a class before a certain element

Tags: jquery

I want to know how many elements of a certain class appear in the DOM before an element that let's say has been clicked on.

```
<html>
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
      <div class="a">
      </div>
  </div>
  <button>CLick me!</button>
  <div class="a">
  </div>
</html>
```

So in the previous DOM tree if the element to be clicked is the button, and Im looking for divs with class "a" it should return 2, even though in the whole tree there are 3, but "before" the button there are only 2.

How could I do that?

Thanks

[EDIT]
The search of elements starts at the begining of the DOM tree until the clicked element. Don't assume that structure, where the elemets are sibilings of the clicked element, it can have any kind of structture.

Comment: What do you think about this? Too time consuming? It solves the problem...
__$(this).parents().prevAll().find('.a').length__
Being $(this) the clicked button.

Answer (score 2):

get all previous nodes matching `.a`, then get all previous nodes' descendants matching `.a` and add together:

```
var count = $('button').prevAll( '.a' ).length;
count += $('button').prevAll().find('.a').length;
console.log( count );
```

Comment: I will edit my question so you understand what I really need.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this, getting all prev elements that match the class, then all children of those prev elements that match the class.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var prev = $(this).prevAll(this.className);
    console.log( prev.length + prev.find(this.className).length );
});
```

not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log(
             $('.a')
                   // get all with class=a not including all after..descendants after  
                   .not($this.nextAll('.a'), $('.a',$this.nextAll('*')))
                   // get number of elements returned
                   .length
     );

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gz9v2/